# Warning: Unable to load Toolbox Path Cache in a for loop

Tags: matlab

I have a code that is like this

```
    echo "try;
  start=tic;

    sv=fopen('$SIZE_VECTOR_1','r');
    vector=fscanf(sv, '%d');
    fclose(sv);

    tama=fopen('$TAMANO_EVAL','r');
    taman=fscanf(tama, '%d');
    fclose(tama);

    fid=fopen('$LISTA_WORDS_EVAL','r');
    lista=fscanf(fid,'%f',[taman,vector]);
    fclose(fid);

    v_writehtk('${OUT_DIR_FEA_EVAL}/${name}.fea',lista,0.01,6);
    toc(start)
    catch
      disp('THROWN MATLAB ERROR:');
      e=lasterror;
      disp(e);
      e.message
      e.stack.file
      e.stack.name
      e.stack.line
    end

" > ${OUT_DIR_VEC_EVAL}/${M_FILE}.m;
```

I have to do this matlab code multiple times in a loop with different values, It is a "for loop" that takes different files with different names, so the for loop is in my shell script code and at each loop this matlab code is created in a txt file and then executed by matlab, I am not doing it in parallel. v_writehtk is a matlab code that transform the files taked by the loop and transforms it to another format. 
sometimes in the loop I receive the Warning: Unable to load Toolbox Path Cache , so I want to know whether or not this affect to my results and how can I solve this?, I tried things like "exit" at the end of the code or "rehash toolboxcache" at the beginning and end of the code but I keep receiving this warning sometimes. Please someone help me on this.

Comment: What loop? Where is the loop? Are you launching MATLAB repeatedly in a shell script? Maybe in parallel? What is `v_writehtk`? Does it modify the MATLAB path?

Comment: It is a "for loop" that takes different files with different names, so the for loop is in my shell script code and at each loop this matlab code is created in a txt file and then executed by matlab, I am not doing it in parallel. v_writehtk is a matlab code that transform the files taked by the loop and transforms it to another format. No I don't change matlab's path

Comment: each loop takes a new file with a different name and a new txt file with the matlab code is created and executed by matlab

Comment: Please answer these questions by [edit]ing your post. I think you need to include the code with the loop that runs MATLAB, and also include complete MATLAB code (preferably by seeing if the error also happens if you don’t call `v_writehtk`, and leaving out that call from your question). See [mre]. Also, what platform are you on?